# Jquery slider to show when you click on links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create a slider for 2 forms that i have.. basically I am going to have Form 1 and Form 2 as text.I would like that when I click on Form 1, a form in a table will slide and become visible underneath the text Form1.... Then if i click Form 2, another form in a table will be visible underneath the text Form 2.... Any help please? thanks

Comment: any help... do you want us to do it for you?

Comment: So you want to dynamically add rows to a table, and maybe animate that?

Comment: Downvoted: It's basically a 'Please write this code for me'-question, instead of a 'I'm stuck on X'-kinda question. You should at least show some effort.

Comment: to those who said that I didnt show my effort, here is the result i got http://www.gfi.com/pages/test-form22.asp ..... the problem I am having is that ON IE9 with compatibility mode enabled, the forms are disappearing... any help pleas?

Answer (score 1):

use like use form, button instead of anchor and div tags

http://www.queness.com/post/3669/create-a-custom-content-slider-with-jquery

More fancy forms:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/07/fancy-sliding-form-with-jquery/